# How to make optional generic in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I created a function for selecting an element

```js
function select(selector: string, parent: Document | Element | HTMLElement = document): Element | HTMLElement | null {
  return parent.querySelector(selector)
}
```

The above function working just fine but then I realized there will some use cases where only specifying that the above functions is returning `HTMLElement` not enough. Sometimes the type of element may be `HTMLInputElement` etc. So to cope with the situation I made my functions generic

```js
function select<T>(selector: string, parent: Document | Element | HTMLElement = document): Element | HTMLElement | T | null {
  return parent.querySelector(selector)
}
```

but by doing this I am losing possible methods on that element. To better understand take a look at the below example :

```js
select('.container')
```

by using the above code I am not getting autocompletion of available methods. Now the next example where I am getting *autocompletion of available methods.*

```js
select<HTMLDivElement>('.container')
```

> What I have tried so far is; On SO itself I found an answer which states make `T = void` then the generic will become optional but still I am not getting autocompletion.

**P.S** - suggest a better title for this post.

Comment: Overloads should work https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwKYBtXQBRs9OAJwC4UpCYwBzAGkQAcBDQ1MKAflIBE4IQBbVlEQAfRAFFMgtqMQAJACoBZADKTU0qAEpS6zbMWq9Q2WBDp0iAFChIsBCgxYoAHgWJUADyisAJsgkpEzFDNSCZAD5cJwISMgpqOiYWNk5EHj59MWMZEOUwjSEdRHcxMwsbcGh4JDxnaPwoIlJkckpaBmYhbl4BYMDC3Pl8nOEAXkRfXs1i0YMR8OEy80sAbytERBYoEEIkZKEAOgBHEFRCAE8AZRimwgbnIi0rAF8rOpwAckOIBChGSjnT7PD6uUJcGAAN1GUW+vzYALAQK0QA Generally avoid type parameters that are only used in one position. Assertions are probably more clear about what is going on `select('.container') as HTMLDivElement`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Thanks!! instead of making things complicated I would rather go with your answer. Type assertion is the most straightforward and easy method.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `extends` to specify the base type of the generic

```
function select<T extends Element = Element>(selector: string, parent: Document | Element | HTMLElement = document): T | null {
  return parent.querySelector(selector)
}
```

Comment: Why not `<T extends HTMLElement = HTMLElement>` or `<T extends Element | HTMLElement = Element | HTMLElement>` ??

Comment: You can definitely go for it, HTMLElement extends Element AFAIK, so either way you'll get the default suggestions